# PhpStorm Automatic upload after checkout not working

Tags: phpstorm

I do not understand why after checkout branch PhpStorm doesn't upload changes to the server.

In `Tools -> Deployment -> Options` I have activated "Upload external changes" option.

Also I have default server configured in `Tools -> Deployment -> Configuration` as well as `Tools -> Deployment -> Automatic upload (always)` option active.

I cloned project from git repository and in PhpStorm I can see all branches. I can create/checkout branches but automatic upload is not happening after checkout.

Comment: Try `File | Synchronize` to re-read project files. Should work -- here users asking opposite behaviour -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-16953 . Other than that -- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-2171 perhaps?

Comment: It did not help me :(

Comment: Hi Viktor, I have the same issue, I have to demo the changes but my branch isn't updating my local repo and the live site. Have you found a good solution?

Comment: @Dgloria sorry but you ask me in the question which was asked almost 6 years ago. I don't remember